# Check whether there is a space before and after a character to perform string splitting

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to split a string based on the `-` character and insert the words before and after the `-` character into a list (`result`) both words with different indexes. What I am trying to achieve is to check whether there is a space before and after the character `-`. If there is space found, perform the splitting as mentioned earlier. Otherwise, if there is no space before or after `-`, do not perform any splitting.

Example:

String1 = London - United Kingdom

String2 = Paris-France

Split `String1` and insert `London` with `index(0)` and `United Kingdom` with `index(1)` into the `result` list because there is space before and after the `-`

Do not split `String 2` and insert `Paris-France` with `index(0)`because there is no space before and after `-`.

Code:

```
        Dim result As New List(Of String)()

        For Each str_get As String In Split

            If (str_get.IndexOf("\t-\t")) Then

                Dim splitStr = str_get.Split({"-", "/"}, StringSplitOptions.None) 

                For Each str_split As String In splitStr 'Add to result list

                    result.Add(str_split.Trim()) ' Enter into result list

                    ' result.TrimExcess()
                Next

            Else


            End If
```

`Split` Is a string which may be considered as an array of strings. The `For` loop is to take each string in that Array and check it.

Any Thoughts or suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Simply try splitting on `" - "` instead of `"-"`. It should work</strike>

**EDIT:**

Ok, just verified that `String.Split` doesn't work that way (with a `String` separator)

This will work:

`splitStr = Regex.Split(str_get, " - ")`

[Demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/jfVPNa)

Comment: are you using .net's String.Split?

Comment: Yes, I am using .Net String.Split

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Dim splitStr = str_get.Split({" - ", "/"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

instead of:-

```
Dim splitStr = str_get.Split({"-", "/"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirement:

```
Dim splits = From str In strings
             Let parts = str.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             Select parts.ToList()
Dim result As List(Of List(Of String)) = splits.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out if your text contains " - " which is SPACE HYPHEN SPACE you can simply test with this statement.......

```
If Instr(DataToTest, " - ") > 0 Then
  'contains the space hyphen space values
Else
  'does not contain space hyphen space
End If
```

Where DataToTest is the string of text you want to test